# Log file locking issues in Batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which starts a Java server class. The output of the Java is redirected to a log file. This batch file is stared via a windows service. Problem is this log file is becoming very huge. Since the Java server is running, it is not possible to do any modification in the Log file as it is locked. How can I create a new log file for every day?

My idea was to write another batch file which will stop the service, backup the existing log file, delete and start the service file again. Is this approach correct?

```
java -Xms32m -Xmx256m gtServer >> abclog.txt
```

Above is the code in the batch file which starts the sever

Any tips on how we could back up the file without stopping the java server?

Thanks in advance

Karthik

Comment: You could do that, or if the server already has it own log creating service, renaming the file according to the date will suffice (Ex. DD-MM-YY.log). However, this is only possible if the server ever stops.

Answer (score 0):

Heard about [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)?

Ok, seriously, would it be possible to use some proper logging facility? It usually provides something for this purpose like [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html).

Comment: Yes but this is already an existing app. Lets assume in this case i am only an admin for maintenance